# Showing array content on a button, using a label

Tags: arrays, swift

I have searched around but have not found an answer. It may be simple but I can nor figure out how you are suposed to do it. So...

I want a button to show an array on a label. When I press the first time, the label show the first number in the array, an pressing a second time makes the label print the second number in the array.

```
var primeString = ["60","52","81","61","85"]
@IBOutlet var PrimeLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func NewAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Here is where I want to make the label show the array in the order when I press it.
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when the button is pressed and we're already displaying the last string in the array?  And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to get this straight. Each time you press the button you want to display the next element in the array through the label. Okay, that should be fairly simple. Something like below will do that for you.

```
var primeString = ["60","52","81","61","85"]
var currentElement = 0

@IBOutlet var PrimeLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func NewAction(sender: AnyObject) {
   if currentElement < primeString.count {
      PrimeLabel.text = primeString[currentElement]
      currentElement++
   } else {
      print("No more elements to display.")
   }
}
```

No need to have the view did load, as we don't need to do any setup once the view has loaded. I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable `count` and initialise to 0

```
var primeString = ["60","52","81","61","85"]
var count = 0
@IBOutlet var PrimeLabel: UILabel!
```

And then action for Button Click.

```
@IBAction func NewAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    PrimeLabel.text = primeString[count%primeString.count]
    count++
}
```

Comment: `count%primeString.count` will reset the head to start of the array

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `Generator` for this?

E.g. something like:

```
var primeStringGenerator = ["60","52","81","61","85"].generate()
@IBOutlet var PrimeLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func NewAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    PrimeLabel.text = primeGenerator.next() ?? "n/a"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var primeString = ["60","52","81","61","85"]
@IBOutlet var PrimeLabel: UILabel!
var number = 0

@IBAction func NewAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        PrimeLabel.text = primeString[i]
        i++
}
```