# How to check if input from UITextField matches Core Data attribute in array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

I have a Core Data object that has two attributes, question and answer. I also have a view that has a label, a UITextField and a button. I want to show the question attribute in the label and then in the UITextField type in the answer attribute for that question to check if it is correct.

So, in viewDidLoad, I ran a fetch on my Card object and put the results into an array. I followed [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856084/showing-array-content-on-a-button-using-a-label) in order to figure out how to iterate through the array to show each question attribute in the label, but now I am unsure how exactly to check the answer attribute for that question. Below is my source code:

```
var cardFetch = [Card]()
var count = 0
@IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var inputText: UITextField!

@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    displayLabel.text = cardFetch[count%cardFetch.count].question
    count++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {
   if let questionString = cardFetch[count%cardFetch.count].question as? String {
       displayLabel.text = questionString
       count++
   }   
}

@IBAction func checkAnswer(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let answerString = cardFetch[count%cardFetch.count].answer as? String {
        if let unwrappedTextfieldString = inputText.text as? String {  
            if answerString == unwrappedTextfieldString {
               // Do whatever you want here
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Note the unwraps that make optional unwrapping crash safe.

Comment: Forgive me if i am misunderstanding, but i need to access the answer attribute from the Card object in my array. I am accessing the question attribute to display in the label, and i want to input the answer attribute related to that question into the textfield.

Comment: Check my edit please. I don't know what the naming in your project is so I'm not sure if pseudo code like cardFetch[count%cardFetch.count].answer going to work, but my answer should show you the logic.

Comment: Only seems to be working when i delete count++. Should i be doing this some cleaner way rather than cardFetch[count%cardFetch.count].answer?

Comment: Copied count++ from your question. You'd better initialize variables out of these buttons methods.